# Is it reasonable to use a current limiting diode in place of a fuse?

Tags: diodes, fuses, current-limiting

I'm trying to source some fast-blow 5mA or 10mA fuses but [Littelfuse has discontinued the only reasonably affordable ones I have found](http://www.littelfuse.com/products/fuses/cartridge-fuses/3ab_3ag-6_3x32mm-fuses/312.aspx).  My circuit when operating properly will not output more than 2mA, however I'd like to ensure if it fails nothing will go over 5mA or 10mA.

Could I substitute something like this [current limiting diode](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Semitec/E-452/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtQ8nqTKtFS%2fG7SPLwmKeGyNUAmd2A%252bGEA%3d) instead?

This is the circuit

[image]

Comment: What does your circuit look like?

Comment: @EMFields - [This is the circuit](http://www.cosmonautdreams.com/images/circuit.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, if you have DC, can live with the 100V rating, and don't mind losing a few volts across the "fuse".

If you're trying to protect something exquisitely sensitive keep in mind that any kind of significant capacitance after the 'fuse' can produce a lot of fault current irrespective of any supply limits.

Answer (score 1):

If your power supply is (say) 30V (maybe an op-amp supply) and you use a current limiting diode of 10mA, if the circuit you wish to protect went short circuit, the power dissipation in the diode would be 300 mW and might exceed limits for the device.

The other problem is that a current limiting diode will "lose" a volt or two in normal operation so you will inevitably reduce your power rail by this amount in normal operation: -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you'll need to change your design. The problem is that, while a fuse typically has a resistance of a few ohms or less, CLDs have significantly larger equivalent resistances. In the case of the 4 mA CLD you refer to, at lower currents it behaves pretty much like a 1k resistor. For a "normal" output of 2 mA, this obviously means that you will lose about 2 volts. You can get around this easily enough by incorporating the CLD inside a feedback loop, such as

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUvbYm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

but you do have to do it. And if you're using 3.3 volt supplies and a 0 - 2 volt output swing you're just entirely out of luck (SOOL, as we used to say).

Comment: Thanks, I dont think I can lose the volts, so Im back to sourcing a fuse.  Appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PNP BJT current source, If you design it to limit at 10mA, R_sense would be about 70 Ohms (assuming 0.7V drop in the P-N junction). This arraignment under your normal operation would drop your rail voltage by 140mV plus the emitter-collector voltage about ~200mV so a total around 350mV, The question is if this voltage drop would be acceptable for your system.

[image]

For 3.3V you could possible replace Q1, with a P Channel MOSFET with Vgs(threshold) of a 1V or 2V and low Rds(on) in order to avoid the extra voltage drop cause by the saturation of the BJT

Comment: That looks similiar to [this circuit](https://www.icmag.com/ic/showpost.php?s=884f8759dd61e65207fcb2a10fb3b226&p=5916346&postcount=24) which uses a MOSFET

Comment: Yes, except the circuit that you show there is a low side current limiting, while the circuit I showed its a high side current limiting. The circuit you found is less complex but it also will not protect against short circuits. In the circuit shown if something happened to short the LED string in the middle it will destroyed the LED from power source to where the short is located. High side circuit limiting would protect and current limit if there was a short on the load at the price of slightly higher complexity